# Displaying Grand Total in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have "Tablix1" which gives sum of the Tablix1TotalAmount field and I have "Tablix2" which gives sum of the Tablix2TotalAmount field. I need to get the sum of these two Total Amounts in say TextBox, Grand total. 
Example:  Grand Total = Sum of (Tablix1TotalAmount + Tablix2TotalAmount)

Please advice, what expression should I specify in Grand Total.

Thanks,
Ken.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
=SUM(Fields!Tablix1TotalAmount.Value, "Tablix1") + SUM(Fields!Tablix2TotalAmount.Value, "Tablix2")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. But I tired this before but not working. For some reason in the Fields!Tablix1TotalAmount.Value, it shows unknown value. I replaced the Tablix1 with Dataset name too, even then its not working. Do you have any other solution besides this.  Thanks, Ken.

Comment: Can't think of much else off the top of my head.  Is it throwing an error in preview mode, or just calculating incorrectly?  Are the fields really called 'Tablix1TotalAmount', or is that an aggregation of another field?  The expression above should use the underlying data field...